# C - Saving a Small File As a String

Tags: c, string, file

Hey guys...In C, I wish to read a file in my current working directory (nothing fancy), into a string. Later, I'd like to print that string out so I can do some work on it. I'm more used to Java, so I'm getting my chops on C and would love an explanation on how to do this! Thanks fellas...

Comment: google 'c file tutorial' first hit: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C program that will read a file and print it as a string.  The filename is passed as an argument to the program.  Error checking would be a good thing to add.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE    *f;
  char    *buffer;
  size_t  filesize;

  f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  // quick & dirty filesize calculation
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  filesize = ftell(f);      
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

  // read file into a buffer
  buffer = malloc(filesize);
  fread(buffer, filesize, 1, f);

  printf("%s", buffer);

  // cleanup
  free(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now that I look at it, I don't know off the top of my head if `buffer` is really going to be null terminated or not.  Be careful out there!

Comment: The buffer is definitely not guaranteed to be NUL-terminated. The other obvious (to me) bad thing that could happen is a NUL character in the file, but I'd say "nothing fancy" probably means that won't happen. And reader should note that adding error checking isn't simple - what you see here is less than half the size of the final error-proof code. fread's postconditions especially are quite subtle, it's allowed to part-complete.

Answer (score 2):

You will use:

```
FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
```

To open the file.  If that returns non-null, you can use:

```
char buf[MAXIMUM_LINE_SIZE];    /* pick something for MAXIMUM_LINE_SIZE... */
char *p;

while ((p=fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)))
{
   /* Do something with the line pointed to by p */
}
```

To do something more sophisticated (not bounded by an arbitrary size, or spanning multiple lines) you'll want to learn about dynamic memory allocation: the functions `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()`...

Some links to help you:

- manpages for file I/O: [fopen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/), [fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/), [fclose](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fclose/)
- for memory allocation: [malloc](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/)

Also, just to throw it out there: If you are interested in writing C++ instead of C, that also has its own file I/O and string stuff that you may find helpful, and you won't have to do all the memory allocations yourself.  But even then, it's probably good to understand the C way also.

Answer (score 1):

You might start with `fopen` and `fread`.

Comment: Sure, though the sequential and small nature of the file reading in this case makes it less likely I think.